# Use the trained k-NN classifier model to classify new, previously unseen objects

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, coursera-api

```
fruit_prediction = knn.predict([[20, 4.3, 5.5]])

lookup_fruit_name[fruit_prediction[0]]
```

I am not able to run above two lines. I am getting this kind of error

ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension

Comment: Can please elaborate more on the output of fruit_prediction and about the lookup_fruit_name and where are you getting this error is it in knn then your input dimensions are wrong

Comment: it says I am getting an error on `fruit_prediction = knn.predict([[20, 4.3, 5.5]])` this particular line

Comment: yup then see the dimension of inputs in the knn

Comment: @AnshuGoyal what is `X_train.shape`?

Comment: It is (44,4) @Harpal

Comment: Your training data has 4 columns but your predicting with 3 columns. Hence, why you are getting the error.

Comment: But the same code I sent to my friend in his it was running properly with no error

Answer (score 0):

Checking the inputs of knn classifier would be good option to analysed what is wrong in the dimensions of knn.predict.
As you have nested list in your predict as inputs that can be just a list.

Comment: for knn.predit first I am doing fit for it which is `knn.fit(X_train, y_train)` and fruit_prediction is just a temp variable I am assigning it too.

Comment: can you try this knn.predict([[20], [4.3], [5.5]])

Comment: can you tell me the X_train dimensions as from the documentation x_train looks like this X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]] and they are using predict function as this knn.predict([[1.1]]), so you can need to look at X_train sample once.

Comment: My x values looks like `X = fruits[['mass', 'width', 'height']]` so in order my 20g is my mass, 4.3cm width and 5.5cm height

Comment: it kind of getting complicated here, what is fruits here. if it possible to upload the complete code please update the question

Comment: It's long and plus I am doing it on Jupyter Notebook. If you feel like we communicate via discord or any other platform in order that I can screen share and you can look at my code?

Comment: just print x train and observe the data that will resolve the problem

Comment: That's the whole output I am getting, I trying to find out the fruit label after passing those parameters

Comment: according to what you have told     fruit_prediction = knn.predict([[20, 4.3, 5.5], [20, 4.4, 5.6]])       sholud have worked

Comment: Yes, maybe the issue is with the version I guess